# ImportXML based on cell value?

Tags: google-sheets-formula

This is my import HTML function:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.zhongnan2017.com/pack/wap/container/getPurchaseSpecInfo.htm?customerName=Daravuth&courierNo=510348&orderNo=&customerPhone=","/html/body/section/ul/li/ul/li[3]/span")
```

I like to extract specific value from the webpage based on certain cell value, for example:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.zhongnan2017.com/pack/wap/container/getPurchaseSpecInfo.htm?customerName=Daravuth&courierNo="&B2"&orderNo=&customerPhone=","/html/body/section/ul/li/ul/li[3]/span")
```

it is a no go for this one!

Any tips or solutions that I could overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

*Change this part of the formula `courierNo="&B2"&` to `courierNo="&B2&"&` and see...*